# Azure Pipeline in queue?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[This is my folder Structure in code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgBhv.png)

Here is my azure-pipeline01.yml

```
  trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - release/*
      - feature/*
      - bug-fix/*
  paths:
    include:
      - OutSideFolderEAIL/Folder01
    exclude:
      - OutSideFolderEAIL/Folder02



pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  mydate: $(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd__hhmmss)


jobs:
  - job: firstjob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        New-Item -Path . -Name "$(Build.DefinitionName)__$(Build.SourceBranchName)__$(Build.BuildId)__$(mydate).dacpac" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
        dir
  - job: SecondJob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "executing azure-pipeline01.yml"
```

Here is my azure-pipeline02.yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
      - release/*
      - feature/*
      - bug-fix/*
  paths:
    include:
      - OutSideFolderEAIL/Folder02
    exclude:
      - OutSideFolderEAIL/Folder01



pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  mydate: $(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd__hhmmss)

jobs:
  - job: firstjob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        New-Item -Path . -Name "$(Build.DefinitionName)__$(Build.SourceBranchName)__$(Build.BuildId)__$(mydate).dacpac" -ItemType "file" -Value "This is a text string."
        dir
  - job: SecondJob
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "executing azure-pipeline02.yml"
```

I want to execute azure-pipeline01.yml and the azure-pipeline02.yml one by one in sequence using 3rd pipeline called as "azure-pipeline-all.yaml" ? how to achieve the same? azure-pipeline-all.yaml will be manually triggered always.

Comment: Any One can help on this .

Comment: Why don't you use templates instead?
You can template the process into a separate yaml file and then execute it multiple times, using parameters to personalize it for your need.
Here is the link to the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#template-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You add two stages in azure-pipeline-all.yaml:

```
stages:
- stage: pipeline01
  displayName: Trigger azure-pipeline01
  jobs:
    - job: RunTests
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: Dummy
        displayName: 'Dummy Do Nothing'
        continueOnError: false
        inputs:
          targetType: Inline
          script: |
            echo "Dummy"
  - stage: pipeline02
    displayName: Trigger azure-pipeline02
    dependsOn:
    - pipeline01
    jobs:
      - job: RunTests
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: Dummy
          displayName: 'Dummy Do Nothing'
          continueOnError: false
          inputs:
            targetType: Inline
            script: |
              echo "Dummy"
```

Then, in `Pipeline01` and `Pipeline02`, you add the trigger:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
 vmImage: ubuntu-latest
resources:
 pipelines:
 - pipeline: MyCIAlias  
   source: azure-pipeline-all
   trigger:    
    stages:        
    - pipeline02 #This is Triggered when stage pipeline02 of pipeline azure-pipeline-all has finished
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines

However, if you want `Pipeline02` to wait for `Pipeline01` to finish, it becomes more tricky: you *could* just skip azure-pipeline-all all together and just trigger `Pipeline02` when `Pipeline01` finishes, using the same concept of `resources.pipelines` triggers.